# Python FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'post.jpg' but he found it there

Tags: python, python-3.x

Dear stackoverflow community,
I have the following problem. I tried to select a random image from my 'uploads' folder. With this line of code:

```
upload = random.choice(os.listdir("/Instagram Bot/Quote Script/upload/"))
```

I also tried

```
upload = random.choice(os.listdir("C:\\Instagram Bot\\Quote Script\\upload\\"))
```

but I keep getting this error:

```
with open(fname, "rb") as fhandle:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'post.jpg'
```

The funny thing is that I didn't specify that picture exactly, but he still found a picture (which is actually in the folder) but says it is not in the folder. What can I do? Best wishes.

Comment: `os.listdir` returns the filename not the full path.

Comment: So how can I get rid of the error? @MauriceMeyer

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Just some suggestions: 1) never name a folder/file with spaces instead use `_` 2) When working with links/paths use `r" path/link" ` this treat backslashes as literal characters. Called `raw strings`

Answer (score 2):

```
upload = random.choice(os.listdir("/Instagram Bot/Quote Script/upload/"))
```

This line will return you a file name something like `example.txt`. If you now want to open the file you have to enter a relativ path or a the whole paht so if you want to open it try something like

```
with open("C:\\Instagram Bot\\Quote Script\\upload\\"+fname, "rb") as fhandle:
    #TODO Write some code
```

Comment: `os.path.join`...